# Realm keeps deleting symbol files

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, app-store-connect, realm

I was getting this annoying BCSymbolMap error described [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14729).
When validating an archive, I couldn't include app symbols and bitcode at the same time.

To try to solve it I removed all my frameworks and added them back. When I removed Realm and dragged it back to my embedded binaries, the app started validating fine.

Then I kept writing my code, changed some unrelated things, and when I tried to archive and validate it failed again.

So I removed Realm again and dragged it to my embedded binaries again… archived and validated again… and it works.

Some more time passed and it stopped working again, I did it all over again, and then it works… and so it goes.

It looks like every time I want to validate an archive to submit to iTunes connect I'll have to remove Realm and add it back again. It's pretty annoying.

What's happening here?

---

Edit:

It seems Xcode keeps deleting the symbol files, I don't know why.

I added the realm frameworks to source control, replaced them with new ones I had just downloaded and committed them to git, and then I got this:

[image]

The symbol files show up with a question mark, because they weren't there when I did my first commit… so then I used Xcode for a while doing nothing much, and tried another commit:

[image]

Now the files show up with a D, because they were deleted! But I didn't delete them!

And I also have other frameworks installed with their own symbol files and those don't get deleted. Very weird…

---

Edit 2:

When I noticed Xcode was deleting the the symbol files I changed the permissions for the realm frameworks to read only. Then I built my project, and alas:

[image]

The `strip-frameworks.sh` script is trying to `rm` the symbol files, but now I wouldn't let it.

So I took a look inside the script…

```
if [ "$ACTION" = "install" ]; then
  echo "Copy .bcsymbolmap files to .xcarchive"
  find . -name '*.bcsymbolmap' -type f -exec mv {} "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}" \;
else
  # Delete *.bcsymbolmap files from framework bundle unless archiving
  find . -name '*.bcsymbolmap' -type f -exec rm -rf "{}" +\;
fi
```

Why is it necessary to remove the symbol files unless archiving?
Whatever the reason, this is not working as it should. I just removed this part from the script and now everything is working fine.

Comment: Are you running the `strip-frameworks.sh` script as part of your archive process as described in Realm's installation instructions? https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#installation

Comment: Yes, I am. Would not doing it cause this? I just double checked it, but maybe I'm doing something wrong. :/

Comment: No, I don't know what would cause this. Did you file a radar about this? Looks like it might be an Xcode bug.

Comment: Not yet, I'll do it as soon as I have the time. I think the problem really is Xcode, I just edited my question.

Comment: @jpsim Ah! I spoke too soon! It seems the `strip-frameworks.sh` script is precisely what's *causing* the problem. I'll update my question.

Comment: What version of Realm are you using? This is potentially the same issue as this one, which was fixed in 0.97.0: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2968

Comment: I'm using 0.97, but the strip-frameworks script I have is different than the on the github repository. Now I'm on a trip, but I'll try changing the script when I come back. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, the fix hasn't been included in a release yet. We'll be releasing 0.97.1 in the next week or so. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by an issue with how BCSymbolMap files are handled in Realm's `strip-frameworks.sh` script, which was recently fixed in [#3032](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/3032), but hasn't yet been included in an official release. The next release of Realm will include the fix.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. :)